# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_confusion'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run code from a tutorial to get a better understanding of it. I'm halfway done, but upon pasting this line of code, I get an error message that says:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_confusion`

Here's the code:

```
from pandas_confusion import ConfusionMatrix


def iterate_fit_predict_score(number_runs):
    f1_scores = []

    y = reformat(student_data['passed'])

    for num in range(0,number_runs):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = Stratified_Shuffle_Split(X_all, y, num_test)
        clf_SVC = SVC()
        parameters = [{'C':[1,10,50,100,200,300,400,500,1000],
                     'gamma':[1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1e0, 1e1],
                     'kernel': ['rbf']}]

        clf = GridSearchCV(clf_SVC, parameters, scoring = 'f1')
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
        target_names = ["failed","passed"]
        print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred,target_names=target_names))    

        # Print Conf_Matrix
        conf_matrix = pd.crosstab(y_true, y_pred, rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)
        print("\nConf_Matrix:", conf_matrix)

        #Normalize Conf_Matrix:
        conf_matrix_norm = conf_matrix / conf_matrix.sum(axis=1)
        print("\nNormalize Conf_Matrix:", conf_matrix_norm)

        #Generate Confusion Matrix Plot
        conf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
        labels = ['fail','pass']
        pl.title('SVC: Confusion Matrix')
        ax = pl.axes
        sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, 
                xticklabels=labels, 
                yticklabels=labels,
                annot=True, fmt='')
        pl.xlabel("Predicted")
        pl.ylabel("True")
```

[image]

What does it mean? Anyway, this is the [project](https://github.com/Tsmith5151/Student-Intervention/blob/master/student_intervention.ipynb) I am following just in case you want to see the full code

Comment: You have to create module `pandas_confusion` as it's not provided by the library from what I recall.

Comment: how do i create that module?

Comment: It is probably created in the tutorial and has `ConfusionMatrix` class. Please read some basics about the language like [this documentation about modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing pandas_confusion package. On a command prompt, run `pip install pandas_confusion`.